# How to Style the Sidebar?

Tags: react-admin

Just picked up web programming and am trying to change the color of the sidebar background. This works:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme() => ({ 
    drawer: {
        backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'
    },
}));

const MySidebar = (props:any) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Sidebar className={classes.drawer} {...props} />
    );
);
```

... but this doesn't:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme() => ({ 
    drawer: {
        backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'
    },
}));

const MySidebar = (props:any) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Sidebar classes={classes} {...props} />
    );
);
```

Why doesn't it work? And how do I find out what is the css class name to overwrite? I used Chrome's inspector tool and the css class name is "MuiDrawer-docked", so I can't figure out how it ended up to be 'drawer' in the end.

I am also trying to set the width of the sidebar when it is closed to 0 (essentially hiding it). If I put this outside in themes, it works:

```
sidebar: {
    width: 300,
    closedWidth: 0,
},
```

But once I put it in useStyle, it doesn't:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme() => ({ 
    sidebar: {
        width: 300,
        closedWidth: 0,
    },
}));

const MySidebar = (props:any) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Sidebar className={classes.sidebar} {...props} />
    );
);
```

What I want to achieve eventually is the combination of these two (background color change + sidebar width closed to 0), hence the use of 'classes' instead of the className.

Comment: If you are able to customize all this with a custom theme and pass it to the Admin component, why would you want to split the styling in the Sidebar itself?

Answer (score 0):

In your second example it doesn't work because of this line:

<Sidebar **classes**={classes} {...props} />

**classes** should be **className**.

Also, in the first example you accessed the **classes.drawer** object, which actually contains the styling. Whereas in the second example you are just passing the classes object without actually specifying a key it should use.

Finally, in your last example:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme() => ({ 
    sidebar: {
        width: 300,
        closedWidth: 0,
    },
    }));
```

You are trying to use **closedWidth** as a css style. closedWidth does not exist as a css style.

To dynamically change the width of an element in React you probably need to use references to the dom node to change the styling on the fly.

You can find useful information about refs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)